# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero" When sending GAE Entity to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to send an entity retrieved from Google App Engine's datastore to a JSP page. In my servlet I can see that the the entity is restored correctly (I logged a property). But somehow when sending back the response to the JSP page I get the error mentioned in my title.

Here's my Servlet code: `TweetPermalinkController.java`

```
package com.socialwebapp;

import java.io.IOException;
// import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TweetPermalinkController extends HttpServlet {
    
//  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NewTweetController.class.getName());
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String id = req.getPathInfo().split("/")[1];
        System.out.println("25: " + id);
        
        long tweetId = 0;
        
        try{
            tweetId = Long.parseLong(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("35: " + tweetId);
        
        Entity tweet = null;
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        
        Key tweetKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Tweet", tweetId);
        
        try {
            tweet = ds.get(tweetKey);
            
            System.out.println((String) tweet.getProperty("message"));
            
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            req.setAttribute("id", tweetId);
            req.setAttribute("tweet", tweet);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("show_tweet.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Code in `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.socialwebapp.HomePageController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewTweetPage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.socialwebapp.NewTweetController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewTweetPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/new_tweet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TweetPermalinkPage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.socialwebapp.TweetPermalinkController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TweetPermalinkPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tweet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

JSP: `show_tweet.jsp`:

```
<h2>Show Single Tweet</h2>
```

**Here's the logs and errors I see in my console:** https://pastebin.com/gqKvTVBK

---

I don't understand why I see the 4th line of the below lines. The first 3 lines are as expected and I don't understand why I see the name of my jsp file, I am not even logging it anywhere:

> 25: 6544293208522752
>
> 35: 6544293208522752
>
> new
>
> 25: show_tweet.jsp
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "show_tweet.jsp" 35:
> 0

---

I have spent half my day trying to figure this out. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/ghoshabhi/SocialWebApp/

TIA!

Comment: On the first line of the function, write `System.out.println(req.getPathInfo())` to see what the path is. It looks like this function is responding to _/tweet/show_tweet.jsp_ as well as _/tweet/some-id_. Then, find out why this function is getting invoked with the _/tweet/show_tweet.jsp_ address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @pacifier21's comment, I realized that the problem was because of the routing config I had: `/tweet/*`. The route was recursively matched and hence the second time it was only a string name of the jsp file, resulting into error.

I ended up changing the route to `/tweet` and passing the ID as a Query String parameter: `/tweet?id=123`.

I wish there was a better way to pass in data with URL, like: `/tweet/<int:id>` - Like available in all the prominent frameworks!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't? Doesn't Java have variables? Or string escape stuff? Like python (`"Hello %s" % "Abhishek"`). Or maybe even decorators?

Comment: @DaniSpringer: Unfortunately I couldn't find it. It should have been pretty simple like I mentioned: `/tweet/<int:id>`. Probably other frameworks like Spring might have it!

Comment: Hopefully. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much on java but looking at the log it seems the issue is  NumberFormatException TweetPermalinkController.java:30

I would suggest to handle the error better so that the code doesn't execute further if "id" can't be converted. For debugging purpose you might want to 
exit/return.